# get installed os applications with NodeJS and Electron

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, electron

Is there a way to retrieve and execute pre-installed applications from the my app?

Like if I want to execute Photoshop from my app.

What I am looking for is to list down all the installed applications on the os and have them get opened when I click on them. Sort of like "Start Menu".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like `child_process.exec(cmd,function(error,stdout,stderr){}));`

please read [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

For example:

```
child_process.exec('cmd.exe');
```

Comment: Actually no. What I am looking for is to list down all the installed applications on the os and have them get opened when I click on them. Sort of like "Start Menu"

Comment: for windows systems you can execute a powershell command with `child_process()` and `spawn()` from there you can list out all the applications installed.

Comment: I actually couldn't find that command. Also It will be really helpful if I can make the process OS independent.

Comment: As the others likely mentioned you can use the 'child_process.spawn()' or 'exec()' method. For windows try to execute some command like 'psinfo -s' to list all installed software. For mac a command like 'find / -iname *.app' can be suitable. If you need further information about the child process in node have a look at the link in the comment. Example: var child = child_process.exec('psinfo-s', (error, stdout, stderror)=>{console.log(stdout)})

Answer (score 0):

Get Insatlled Apps
Get installed app using Node.js, supporting Windows and macOS.

‍ Install

`npm install get-installed-apps`

Usage
ES6 Module

```
import {getInstalledApps} from 'get-installed-apps'

getInstalledApps().then(apps => {
  console.log(apps)
})
```

CommonJS

```
const {getInstalledApps} = require('get-installed-apps')
getInstalledApps().then(apps => {
  console.log(apps)
})
```

https://github.com/Xutaotaotao/get-installed-apps